# What is the Ideal/best thread pool size when using many executors?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

From many post I can read the formula about the max pool size which depends on the number of CPU + 1. That's a clear explanation.

But what if the application has many of the Executor's or ThreadPoolExecutor's defined. We must then also consider that the application shares the same hardware. How this has impact on the pool size selection.

Do we need to calculate globaly the size and the divide it depend on the number of the defined thread pools?

Comment: Yes. Yes you do. But even that "rule" that you have is not very useful - are your threads IO bound? In which case they'll spend most time sleeping - so you can have more than the number of CPUs (for example a web server). Are your threads memory bound? CPU bound? All this has an effect. These sorts of "rules" are rarely, if ever, useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `nosCPUs + 1` "rule of thumb" assumes that the threads will be CPU bound (not I/O bound) and there won't be significant lock contention.  This is not realistic for typical applications.

If you have multiple thread pools, you also have to consider whether the threads in the respective pools are going to be busy at the same time.

- If they are AND the previous assumptions are true for all pools, then the `nosCPUs + 1` rule can be applied globally; i.e. to sum of of the sizes of all pools.
- Otherwise, figuring out a formula that predicts the optimal size for the pools is most likely too complicated.

---

In practice, the behavior of *typical* multi-threaded applications is sufficiently complicated that the `nosCPUs + 1` rule doesn't give the optimal thread count.  Furthermore, you typically can't derive a formula that would allow you to accurately predict the optimal thread count.

Instead, it is common practice to make your thread pool size / sizes a tunable parameter or property, and tune them to get good performance for a *typical* workload.  It will make tuning easier if your application has just one thread pool, though there may be reasons not to do it that way.

But the good news is that the performance impact of a bounded thread pool that is *a bit too big* is generally not significant.  The problems arise (memory usage, contention, context switching, etc) when the pool size is *way too big*.

---

Finally, I think you should review the decision to have many executors each with its own thread pool.  This is liable to lead to memory wastage due to thread stacks for (long-term) idle threads in multiple pools.  Furthermore, the task of tuning the pool sizes will be harder if you have many pools to tune individually.  Conversely, if you have a single "tuning knob" for all of the pools, you end up tuning the pool sizes for the worst case of all of the pools.

You need to weigh these issues / costs against the benefits to your application of having many executors.  (I can see that there would be benefits in some use-cases ...)